# git-diff: Only show changes staged for committing

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to see diff on files that I've added to commit (`git add something`). I can do this:

```
git diff HEAD `git status -s | grep ^M | cut -c 4-`
```

Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `git diff --staged` (or `git diff --cached`) to see the diff that will be used when committing.

From the manpage:

> `git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]`
>    This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the named `<commit>`. Typically you would want comparison with the latest commit, so if you do not give `<commit>`, it defaults to `HEAD`. If `HEAD` does not exist (e.g. unborned branches) and `<commit>` is not given, it shows all staged changes. `--staged` is a synonym of `--cached`.